# What is the difference between .length and .length() in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I am just wondering if `.length()` is just an alias of `.length` because they return the same result:

```rb
[38] pry(main)> temp = [1,2,3]
=> [1, 2, 3]
[40] pry(main)> temp.length
=> 3
[41] pry(main)> temp.length()
=> 3
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no difference. In Ruby, you can omit the parentheses around arguments in many cases.

```
temp.length
temp.length()
```

are identical. The same is true for

```
temp.push(4)
temp.push 4
```

Comment: That's fancy. Is that meant so that it can function in both command line and in class like structures or at least maybe say the syntax of command line can also work in class like structures?

Comment: @Honey It's just less clutter, which is one of Ruby's sort of design aesthetics. `x.y.z` looks cleaner than `x().y().z()` and makes a lot of things neat and tidy in Ruby that are downright ugly in other languages.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that there are cases where you want to use them, or need to, like in the case of `temp.push 4 * 5` or `temp.push(4) * 5` which mean two very different things.

Comment: You need the parens if you are passing arguments and a block as a one liner e.g. `fn(a, b) { |c| }`  or when the commas between the arguments would be ambiguous, e.g. `[fn(1), fn(2)]` or `fn fn(a), fb(b)` ... but the parser will never require the parens if you're not pasing any arguments

Comment: Also the Error message in case of a typo is more precise: `rnd` =>NameError (undefined local variable or method rnd for main:Object)
 versus `rnd()` =>NoMethodError (undefined method rnd for main:Object)

Answer (score 3):

**In Ruby, when you define or call (execute, use) a method,
you can omit the parentheses.**

So these lines mean exactly the same:

```
temp.length
temp.length()
```

http://ruby-for-beginners.rubymonstas.org/bonus/parentheses.html

Answer (score 0):

Just an addition to these answers.

You can also omit parentheses on method definitions as well, not only method calls.

For example:

```rb
def length
  1
end
```

```rb
def length()
  2
end
```

http://ruby-for-beginners.rubymonstas.org/bonus/parentheses.html